# I need to think like a programmer: Childs and Parents in Cocos2d, program structure, enums etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coding-style, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a completely self-taught Objective-C programmer, and I need advice on how to best structure a project that I'm working on.

I'm dealing with `CCSprite`'s, `.tags`, and some general program structure issues that I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to go about structuring the program.

As of right now, the program is running exactly how I want it to, but it seems like I'm wasting lines of code and being overly redundant. I want to save myself some trouble in the future and get everything done right up front.

I am essentially creating a fully-animatable rigged character out of `CCSprites`. I need each part of his body to animate independently of other body parts. To achieve this, I've created a method that I call in the `-init` method of my `CCScene`, which goes through and creates the `CCSprites` and parents them to the appropriate part. Here is the code for the method:

```
-(void) characterInit{
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

//Torso

CCSprite * torso = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Torso.png"];
torso.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, .5);
torso.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
torso.scale = 1;
torso.tag = torsoTag;
[self addChild:torso];

//Head

CCSprite * head = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Head.png"];
head.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, 0);
head.position = ccp(50,60);
head.tag = headTag,
[torso addChild:head z:1];

//Eyes

CCSprite * eyes = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Eyes.png"];
eyes.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, .5);
eyes.position = ccp(35, 45);
eyes.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
eyes.tag = eyesTag;
[head addChild:eyes];
...
...
...
```

...this continues on for each body part.

The key here is that I am using just plain old `int`s with a number value for the `.tag` for each `CCSprite`. I declare the `int`s above this method, outside of any other methods so that they are accessible inside the `init` method as well.

**Question 1:** What would be a better way to do this? Maybe as an `enum`? What would that code look like, and is there a better way to generate that code as opposed to just writing out each value, like i did when I had them as `int`s?

Now my next question comes in after I've gone through and created all the `CCSprites`. When I want to use them outside of the method I created them in, I use code like this from my `init` method:

```
        CCSprite * torso = (CCSprite *) [self getChildByTag:torsoTag];
        CCSprite * head = (CCSprite *) [torso getChildByTag:headTag];
        CCSprite * eyes = (CCSprite *) [head getChildByTag:eyesTag];


 [eyes runAction:...];
```

I originally tried simply calling...

```
CCSprite * eyes = (CCSprite *) [self getChildByTag:eyesTag];
```

...but to no avail. I assumed that I would be able to call this individual body part with out having to call in every parent of that body part so that I can animate it. because...well...

That **Sucks.**

The point is this; I feel like I am just thinking about this incorrectly. I want to organize my code, but the whole point of organizing is so that you don't have to be redundant.

**Question 2:** What would a better programmer than myself do to handle this whole freaking situation?

Thanks for your time guys, and sorry for the **WALL OF TEXT**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could forget the whole `tag` business and store the sprites as instance variables of your class.

```
@interface MyClass : MyParentClass {
  @private
  CCSprite *torso;
  CCSprite *head;
  CCSprite *eyes;
}

...

@end
```

Your method would be a little simpler:

```
-(void) characterInit{
  CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

  //Torso

  torso = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Torso.png"];
  torso.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, .5);
  torso.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
  torso.scale = 1;
  [self addChild:torso];

  ...
```

And you can use your body parts directly:

```
[eyes runAction:...];
```

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense. Thanks for your input!

Comment: This will also be faster because each getChildByTag is a lookup in a dictionary. If you use the child quite often then using an instance variable is preferred. Make sure to not retain childs, this can easily create a retain cycle and thus the scene never releasing memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try making *smaller* functions; add methods for adding a torso, head, and eyes, etc. Some of the steps are nearly identical, except for data that could be handled via parameters:

```
torso.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, .5);
head.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, 0);
eyes.anchorPoint = ccp(.5, .5);
```

If you can create a method that contains the steps common to all three body parts and three new methods that handle what is unique to each body part, you could write code more like this pseudo-code:

```
body = new Body();
b.addEyes: "Eyes.png",
    anchor: ccp(.5, .5),
    position: ccp(35, 45),
    color: ccc3(255, 255, 255);
b.addHead: "Head.png",
    anchor: ccp(0, 0),
    position: ccp(100,10);
...
```

Both `addEyes` and `addHead` would call into `addBodyPart` to handle `anchor` and `position`, allowing you to write that code only once.

This might just seem like moving code around; but keeping each method small, doing exactly one thing, typically allows for easier debugging, easier maintenance, and more flexibility.

Comment: This is exactly the type of thinking that I need to more of. I need to abstract the similarities. However, how would you suggest handling things on a less frequent basis? For example, should I try creating a method that has every potential initialization factor included? (scale, anchor, and position, but also color, opacity and whatever else) Or should I try leaving those for a one-off basis somewhere else in my code?